# Java 2d Game: Rendering Q

Tags: java, image, 2d, rendering, frames

I am making a 2d game in Java, and I have some questions abot rendering.

Should I re-draw Objects every Frame althought they are still visible or static? If not how would I detect how an image is not being changed so I would not render it? What things should update everyframe, and what type of images?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using the Graphics class to draw your objects? If so, you do not need to worry about rendering individual frames as long as they are not changing; the Graphics class does that for you. You must override the paintComponent(Graphics g) method for a JComponent (or any of its subclasses) if you are using Swing. If you're using AWT, then you override the paint(Graphics g) method for a Component (or any of its subclasses).

Comment: I would think this comes a lot down how difficult it is to update the screen.  The more complex the update process becomes, the more you need to render elements individually.  Remember, rendering is compounding process.  Unless you completely clear what was previously renderer, you are simply painting over the top of what was already there.  You might consider using a layered approach.  Where you can identify layers of static content and layers of active content and simply rendering the layers over the top of each other as you need.

Comment: My earlier comment that I deleted was incorrect. If you want to ensure that you see a change, you should you should manually call a JComponent's repaint() method to ensure that it's updated immediately. Sometimes you do not have to do this, but it's not reliable so you should do it if you want to see an object updated.

Comment: I use the Graphic class to draw my objects, but when i use the repaint method for the Jframe it clears complely any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases, it's always better to render each object uniquely each frame. If you were to try and figure out what has been previously rendered it would usually take more time to compute that and render the new objects than it would to just clear the screen each frame and render each object.

You can think of what you want to do in terms of something like an MP4 file, this file takes each frame of a movie and does not re-render pixels of the same color in the same area. This makes it so the file size is smaller, but if you tried to do this in a game you would essentially be doing something along the lines of an MP4 compression algorithm each frame.

Another problem, if some objects stayed static, and other objects moved around one frame. It is very hard, if not impossible, to clear the screen of only a select few objects.